# Selecting column based on a field value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I need to select a different column from a database based on a value in a different field.

Players:

```
ID     EVENT_ID     NAME   TEAM  
--------------------------------
1         1         Ann      1
2         1         Bob      2
3         2         Claire   1
```

Events:

```
ID     EVENT_NAME     TEAM_1       TEAM_2    
----------------------------------------------
1      Football       All Stars    Tornadoes   
2      Tennis         Dynamos      Best Team
```

Based on my tables I want to be able to search for player ID 2 and get their team name depending on the players.team value.
so something like this:

```
SELECT players.*,
(SELECT team+"players.team" AS team_name FROM events WHERE players.event_id = events.id)
WHERE players.id = '2'
```

that gets the result:

```
Player.ID:   1
Player.Name: Bob
Team_Name:   Tornadoes
```

Comment: If you designed the `events` table, you need to redesign it.

Comment: Agreed, it's not ideal.

Comment: They're entered again. There's a table with more info on the players (age, points so far etc) but this mini table just has the player, team and event id plus their name in case their profile is deleted so there is still a record of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` for that:

```
    SELECT p.id, p.name, 
           CASE WHEN p.team = 1 THEN e.team_1 ELSE e.team_2 END AS Team_Name 
      FROM Players p 
 LEFT JOIN Events e 
        ON e.id = p.event_id 
     WHERE p.id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id,p.name, IF(p.team = 1,e.team_1,e.team_2)
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN events e ON (p.event_id = e.id)
WHERE p.id = 2;
```